# Issue finding controller concerns only in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autoload

My application has a number of controller concerns in `app/controllers/api/V2/concerns`

When I work on this in development, everything works well. However, as soon as I push to production, I get the following error when the rails server boots up: `Uninitialized constant Concerns::MyConcern (NameError)`

My concerns look like this:

```
module Api::V2
  module Concerns
    module MyConcern
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern

      def some_method(some_arg)
        # some stuff here
      end

    end
  end
end
```

I have set up `config.eager_load = true` in both my production and development environments to try and make them as consistent as possible; however, still not seeing this error occur in production.

What's strange is if I comment out the areas where I include the concerns in the controllers, the application manages to boot up; then, when I go to rails console on the production server and see if I can access Api::V2::Concerns::MyConcern I am able to access it without error. This makes me think that there's some sort of autoloading issue going on where the concerns aren't loaded when they are called in the controllers; however, I was under the impression that Rails loaded up everything in the app/ folder automatically and only areas such as the /lib had to be explicitly added.

As an FYI, my controller sits in `app/controllers/api/V2/my_controller.rb`

Any ideas what could be happening here?

Comment: can you try after restarting production server..?

Comment: I've tried restarting the server, and even deploying to another provider (Heroku) all together and get the exact same error

Comment: Is this called `my_concern.rb`? Are you sure it's all lower case? Sometimes your local dev system is case insensitive, production isn't.

Comment: paste a fullpath to the file, pls

Comment: @tadman yes, this error occurs with all 6 of my concerns. If I comment one out in the controller, the same error occurs on the second one. The fact that if I `rails c` into the application after commenting out all the "includes" and then am able to access those concerns makes me think it is some weird loading issue

Comment: @itsnikolay the full path is /app/controllers/api/V2/concerns/my_concern.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's highly probable that the `V2` component in your path is causing the issue here. On a case insensitive file system this will be resolved as `v2` which works. On a case sensitive file system it will be looking for `app/controllers/api/v2/concerns/my_concern.rb` which doesn't exist, and won't load.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Seems like it was a case issue in the V2 where the file system didn't recognize the capitalization. Thank you!